# Legendre's Polynomial and spherical harmonics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials, sturm-liouville, spherical-harmonics

The differential equation that is satisfied by the Legendre's polynomials is:

$$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + \lambda y = 0 (*)$$

I have also been told that the Legendre's polynomial with the parameter $x = \cos\theta$ satisfies the spherical harmonics:

$$\sin\theta \frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin \theta \frac{dy}{d\theta}) - (m^2 - \lambda\sin^2(\theta))y = 0$$

which is equivalent to (under the substitution $x = \cos \theta$):

$$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' - (\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}- \lambda)y = 0 (**)$$

and the solution for this differential equation is $P(\cos \theta)$. However, I don't see how $(*)$ and $(**)$ compare? The first scalar term in $(*)$ is a constant $\lambda$, but the scalar term in $(**)$ is not: $\frac{m^2}{1-x^2} - \lambda$. Why is are lagrange polynomials a solution for this equation?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions to (**) (when $\lambda=\ell(\ell+1)$ and $0\leq m\leq \ell$, with $\ell,m\in\mathbb{N}$) are the [associated Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials), of which the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) are a special case, corresponding to $m=0$.